# Julia - Check object has attribute

Tags: oop, julia

Suppose I have `struct` as below.

```
struct Foo
    attr1
    attr2
end
```

I can then instantiate and get the `attr1` and `attr2`

```
julia> foo = Foo(1,2)

julia> foo.attr1
1
```

I'm just wondering if I can do any checking that my object `foo` has `attr1`?

For reference, `python` has [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) which exactly what I'm looking for here, but I couldn't seem to find the equivalent in `julia`.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I'm in Julia 1.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you are in julia 1.1 or 1.0, you can define your own `hasproperty`:

```
hasproperty(x, s::Symbol) = s in fieldnames(typeof(x))
```

this is (almost) the same function that is in julia 1.2 base and above

Comment: Thanks! I saw `fieldnames`, but didn't realize it took `::DataTypes` as the argument instead of an object.

Comment: In Julia version >= 1.2 there are two functions, `hasproperty` and `hasfield`. The implementation you have written here seems to be more appropriately named `hasfield`. Properties can be fields, but they can also be 'virtual fields' that are not actually stored. On version 1.0 you could implement `hasproperty` in terms of `propertynames`, instead of `fieldnames`.

Comment: Also note a difference from the python `hasattr` behaviour, which can be used to check if a module contains a function with the given name. For this purpose use Julia's `isdefined`

Answer (score 6):

For Julia v1.2 or above, it is documented here: [`hasproperty`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.hasproperty).

If you are using Julia 1.1.0, then I think you can use that function in [Compat.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl/blob/master/README.md#new-functions-macros-and-methods)

Comment: Ah, unfortunately it requires at least Julia 1.2.0. I'm in Julia 1.1.0, is there any workaround for Julia 1.1.0? Thanks anyway!