# Get all object attributes in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to see the methods, attributes, etc. that a specific object has in Julia. I know some options that may get me part of this are things like [`fieldnames()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687418/how-to-get-fields-of-a-julia-object) or [`hasproperty()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443530/julia-check-object-has-attribute) but is there an option which will give me **all** of the attributes (similar to the [`dir` function in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Retrieving all attributes from a Type

Suppose you have a Type `T`.

To see all **methods** that accept an object of type `T` as an argument, you can do:

```
methodswith(T)
```

To see all **fields** (i.e.: type's "properties"):

```
fieldnames(T)
```

If you want to combine all info into a function, you can do one yourself, like this:

```
function allinfo(type)
   display(fieldnames(type))
   methodswith(type)
end
```

## Retrieving all attributes from an object

If instead of having a Type, you have an object `a`, the procedure is the same, but substituting `T` and  `type` above by `typeof(a)`:

```
# See all methods
methodswith(typeof(a))

# See all fields
methodswith(typeof(a))

# Function combining both
function allinfo(a)
   type = typeof(a)
   display(fieldnames(type))
   methodswith(type)
end
```

## Retrieving all attributes regardless of its nature

Using multiple dispatch, you can define a function with three methods that gets you all info regardless of what you pass as argument.

The third case is needed in case you want to inspect methods that accept Type objects as arguments.

```
# Gets all info when argument is a Type
function allinfo(type::Type)
   display(fieldnames(type))
   methodswith(type)
end

# Gets all info when the argument is an object
function allinfo(a)
   type = typeof(a)
   display(fieldnames(type))
   methodswith(type)
end

# Gets all info when the argument is a parametric type of Type
function allinfo(a::Type{T}) where T <: Type
   methodswith(a)
end
```

Comment: What if I want to pass in an actual object, like `a = [1,2]` and then get the info for `a` itself, not necessarily the type?

Comment: Add `type = typeof(a)` to the top of the function and change the function signature to `allinfo(a)`.

Answer (score 5):

not exactly what you're asking for, but [`dump`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.dump) is pretty handy

```
julia> struct A
           a
           b
       end

julia> dump(A((1,2),"abc"))
A
  a: Tuple{Int64, Int64}
    1: Int64 1
    2: Int64 2
  b: String "abc"
```